# BCC for all DocuSign Envelope SENT Event

Tags: soap, docusignapi

when using DocuSign SOAP API to create envelope and assign a valid email address to BCCEmailAddresses value in the create envelope from template API request boy. However, that email never receive any email during testing.

1. The DocuSign SOAP API guide mentions "BCCEmailAddresses – Only users with canManageAccount setting can use this option.". How to configure that from the latest Demo DocuSign site?
2. Is there way to configure DocuSign site account to BCC every DocuSign envelopes sent to recipients(during SENT event) rather than indicating it in every SOAP Create Envelope API request body?

Comment: Can I ask if there's a strong reason you prefer the SOAP API vs. the REST API?

Comment: We have existing one used since 1995~1996 I believe.

Comment: Wow, that's before DocuSign even existed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a feature that automatically add a BCC recipient for every envelope on the account. It's possible an old feature like that existed a long time ago, but it has been deprecated.
The alternatives:

1. Use [DocuSign Agreement Actions](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-agreement-actions). That capability of taking an action when an envelope was signed to archive it or send it to somewhere.
2. Use a third party API automation tool (like Microsoft PowerAutomate) and add a flow that does this.
3. Use webhook and build a simple integration using DocuSign Connect that sends the email with the completed document to the addresses you specify.

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for your help.  There is a little confusion likely from my question. Let me clarify.  As part of legal compliance, after successfully called DocuSign SOAP API to create envelope with documents sending to customer, we want to archive every envelope that DocuSign initially email/send to customer/recipient at the same time (not sign yet).  We do have existing callback services which listens to DocuSign CONNECT callback for SIGNED event.  The challenges is that we don't want recipient to see and confused by our archiving email address.

Comment: If BCC feature has been deprecated (not sure why deprecates this useful feature), it seems subscribing to DocuSign CONNECT Envelope SENT event is another option.  Other thought is welcome.

Comment: the Agreement Actions feature I linked to can also archive completed envelopes in that way.

Comment: That Agreement Actions feature only handles "post-signature tasks", isn't it? There is listed of trigger events, but I can't tell or see an "SENT" event.  "Sent" I mean to save a copy of envelope email that DocuSign sent to customer for signing concurrently, no the one that customer signed/completed.

Comment: aha, I misunderstood your request. You want to save it BEFORE people sign, not AFTER when the envelope is completed. Then I think using Connect webhook may be your only option .

Comment: Sorry for confusion caused by my question text.  Thanks again for your insightful help.